# USB-C (thunderbolt) on XPS to Displayport: What is the trick?

Tags: displayport, thunderbolt, usb-c

Laptop: Dell XPS 13 w thunderbolt / usb-c port

I have a cable that is USB-C to displayport, but it doesn't work. This forces me to use a Dell usb-c to hdmi adapter, which I would prefer to avoid.

What am I missing to make the direct usbc-displayport work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is.... use the right adapter.

Such as:
http://accessories.us.dell.com/sna/productdetail.aspx?c=us&l=en&s=bsd&cs=04&sku=470-ACFC&dgc=ST&acd=12309152537501410&ven1=sURMYR6t3&ven2=,&ven3=112803309682130213

Comment: What do you mean by use the right adapter? Ensure the ports at both ends are correct or are you referring to brand/quality?

Comment: Ports that look like USB C standard physically are not necessarily the same port electronically, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I used a StarTech usbc to thunderbolt 2 cable from amazon and the apple thunderbolt display now works with my dell precision 5510 (similar to xps 15).  All ports on back of display work except thernet upon connection but i assume added drivers will make it work.